# Need to initialize a byte[] array with ascii blank (i.e. 0x20 OR " ")

Tags: java, android

Hello all Ol' Guy Newbie here ... 
I've defined a string=> final static String Blank     = " " ;
and a byte array 
static byte[] LU62_Partner    = new byte[8] ;

Further down in my logic I want to initialize the byte[] array with blanks

```
     // Prep LU6.2 Session  
 for ( ndx=0 ; ndx < 8 ; ++ndx)
   { 
     LU62_Partner[ndx] = Blank.getBytes() ;    // initialize the the LU6.2 partner name byte array w/blanks  
   }
 LU62_Partner = APPC_Partner.getBytes() ;      // convert string array to byte array 
                                               // if the appc-partner name < 8 bytes, rightmost bytes
                                               // will be padded with blanks
```

However upon compilation I get the following error
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:199: incompatible types
found   : byte[]
required: byte
         LU62_Partner[ndx] = Blank.getBytes() ;

Again I'm confused... I was under the impression that the method getBytes() would convert a string into a byte. 
Thanks very much again

Guy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want that line to be

```
LU62_Partner[ndx] = Blank.getBytes()[0];
```

The variable on the left-hand-side of the assignment is a byte, and so the value on the right-hand-side should also be a byte, not an array of bytes.

In any case, since you're already implicitly assuming that space is a single byte, why not just say

```
LU62_Partner[ndx] = (byte) ' ';
```

or

```
LU62_Partner[ndx] = 0x20;
```

(because hex 20 is space)?

EDIT: and as @MeBigFatGuy points out, `Arrays.fill()` would let you eliminate your explicit loop altogether.

Comment: Well thank you very very much ... I was not aware one could specify a hex value directly in java... 0x20 it is

Answer (score 4):

getBytes() returns an array, so you are attempting to jam an array of bytes into a byte

use

```
Arrays.fill(LU62_Partner, (byte)' ');
```